# U-SQL - SUM of a CASE Statement

Tags: c#, azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I have a table with customer transactions that I'm trying to aggregate by customer and department.

```
Cust_id    trans_num    sku   dept   qty    price
 123         234        345    1      2      15.99
 123         345        887    1      1      12.99
 123         678        445    2      1      21.89
 234         345        998    1      1       7.99
```

In SQL I'd do something like this:

```
SELECT Cust_id
         , SUM(CASE WHEN dept = 1 THEN (price * qty) ELSE 0 END ) dept_1_spend
         , SUM(CASE WHEN dept = 2 THEN (price * qty) ELSE 0 END ) dept_2_spend
from tab1
group by Cust_id
```

The U-SQL docs [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt771654.aspx#case) mention `?` as the `C#` equivalent but I'm not sure how to `SUM` the values.

What's the equivalent in U-SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try ternary operator in C#:

```
SELECT Cust_id
         , SUM(dept == 1 ? price * qty : 0) AS dept_1_spend
         , SUM(dept == 2 ? price * qty : 0) AS dept_2_spend
from tab1
group by Cust_id
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also you the U-SQL `PIVOT` operator, eg

```
@tab1 =
  SELECT *
  FROM(
  VALUES
    (123,234,345,1,2,15.99),
    (123,345,887,1,1,12.99),
    (123,678,445,2,1,21.89),
    (234,345,998,1,1,7.99)) AS T(Cust_id,trans_num,sku,dept,qty,price);


@res =
    SELECT Cust_id,
           SUM([1]) AS dept_1_spend,
           SUM([2]) AS dept_2_spend
    FROM
    (
        SELECT Cust_id, dept, price * qty AS spend
        FROM @tab1
    ) AS t
    PIVOT (SUM(spend) FOR dept IN ( 1 AS [1], 2 AS [2] )
    ) AS pvt
    GROUP BY Cust_id;


OUTPUT @res
TO "/output/sum_case.csv"
USING Outputters.Csv();
```

More information on U-SQL `PIVOT` available [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt781264.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can even use the SQL's `CASE` expression. You will need the C# `==` and use `AS` to designate the column aliases and use upper-case for the keywords. But otherwise looks like your query:

```
@tab1 =
  SELECT *
  FROM(
  VALUES
    (123,234,345,1,2,15.99),
    (123,345,887,1,1,12.99),
    (123,678,445,2,1,21.89),
    (234,345,998,1,1,7.99)) AS T(Cust_id,trans_num,sku,dept,qty,price);

@res =
  SELECT Cust_id,
         SUM(CASE WHEN dept == 1 THEN(price * qty) ELSE 0 END) AS dept_1_spend,
         SUM(CASE WHEN dept == 2 THEN(price * qty) ELSE 0 END) AS dept_2_spend
  FROM @tab1
  GROUP BY Cust_id;

OUTPUT @res
TO "/output/sum_case.csv"
USING Outputters.Csv();
```

I personally prefer the C# ternary if.